# Cannot format an argument. To make type T formattable provide a frormatter <T>

Tags: c++, glfw, spdlog

So im creating a game engine in accordance to thecherno's tutorial and I am adding GLFW Error handling(This is c++) and I cannot figure out  where and how to add a formatter for SPDLOG
Here is my `Log.h`:

```
#define PL_CORE_TRACE(...)      ::Pluton::Log::GetCoreLogger()->trace(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PL_CORE_WARN(...)       ::Pluton::Log::GetCoreLogger()->warn(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PL_CORE_INFO(...)       ::Pluton::Log::GetCoreLogger()->info(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PL_CORE_ERROR(...)      ::Pluton::Log::GetCoreLogger()->error(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PL_CORE_FATAL(...)      ::Pluton::Log::GetCoreLogger()->fatal(__VA_ARGS__)
```

`__VA_ARGS__` is all the arguments given to the logger

I binded an OnEvent Function that logs like so:

```
    void Application::OnEvent(Event& e) {
    PL_CORE_INFO("{0}", e);
}
```

I bound the `glfwSetErrorCallback` event to GLFWErrorCallback function like so:

```
    static void GLFWErrorCallback(int error, const char* description) {
    PL_CORE_ERROR("GLFW Error ({0}): {1}",error,description);
}
//this is a snippit in Application::Init() which initializes GLFW
    if (!s_GLFWInitialized) {
                int success = glfwInit();
                PL_CORE_ASSERT("GLFW NOT INITIALIZED");
                glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWErrorCallback);
                s_GLFWInitialized = true;
            }
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Cannot format an argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization.
```

It is the only error and does not specify which one is causing this error as well as which type that cannot be formatted.

EDIT:

I Created this in which I wanted to return that as the format for the type of `Event` and I put it into my `Log.cpp` file which is imported in every file that uses event. The same error occurs

```
struct fmt::formatter<Pluton::Event> {
    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.begin()) {
        return ctx.end();
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const Pluton::Event& input, FormatContext& ctx) -> decltype(ctx.out()) {
        return format_to(ctx.out(),
            "(Name:{})",
            input.GetName() {});
    }

};
```

Comment: Surely the error comes with a line number. My guess is that you need to provide something like `formatter<Event>`.

Comment: The error is Code:C2338 file:Core.h(of spdlog) line 1728

Comment: The error doesn't show where my script has issues only where spdlog does

Comment: Did you omit part of the error message? Or maybe you don't have the latest version of spdlog. Here is where it comes from: [github.com/.../core.h#L1758](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/8a0b2231b17ff0c084d7319a8631a84bd89181f1/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h#L1758). As you can see, there is an http address included. It will take you to a reference page explaining what you need to do.

Comment: the reference page I cannot understand as it does not allow me to create a formatter struct inside my namespace

Comment: Then don't put it inside your namespace.

Comment: then how do i reference it ?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Why do you want to reference it? If it's in the global namespace, spdlog should be able to see it, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Okay im updating for the next part of this issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `#include <spdlog/fmt/ostr.h>` to `Log.h` file. With this spdlog would be able to use `operator<<` in Event.h

Comment: It's no longer so simple: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#ostream-api